# How I can get HTTP response error message?

Tags: oracle-apex

I make rest request using `APEX_WEB_SERVICE.MAKE_REST_REQUEST` function, when I get unsuccessful response status code (for example 400, 405), I didn't get body, but Oracle Apex Debug Message Data displaying:

> HTTP response 405 - <**message**>

How I can get this message? I try to use `apex_web_service.g_headers` but it doesn't give me it.

[image]
Photo from Apex Debug, where is green border - my custom error, where is red border - Apex. And I think this data from HTTP header or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`APEX_WEB_SERVICE.G_REASON_PHRASE` - that what I need.

Answer (score 2):

as MAKE_REST_REQUEST us a *function*, you should find the response body in the variable you have MAKE_REST_REQUEST assigned to ...

APEX never writes the response body to debug output; but you can do that yourself, as follows:

```
:
l_response := APEX_WEB_SERVICE.MAKE_REST_REQUEST( ... );
if apex_web_service.g_status_code >= 400 then
    apex_debug.info( 'Request Body is %s', sys.dbms_lob.substr( l_response, 4000, 1 ) );
end if;
:
```

Comment: Yes I know, but in my case response body is empty, it's something else, I think is HTTP response header message, but I can't find it, but Oracle Apex gets it. I  have updated my first post, added a photo.